# Как полностью синхронизировать 2 реактивные формы (их значения), если они находятся в разных местах приложения? [Angular + RxJS]

Tags: angular, forms, rxjs

Никак не могу решить такую задачку.

Angular 11 + Angular material.

Компоненты находятся далеко друг от друга.

Есть компонент `checkboxesForm` содержащий в себе реактивную форму состоящую всего из 3х чекбоксов.

Этот самый компонент с чекбоксами размещён в 2х разных отдалённых друг от друга местах приложения (в 2х разных компонентах без общего родителя).

Задача состоит в том чтобы в обоих местах компонент `checkboxesForm` отображал одно и тоже состояние чекбоксов.

Например изначально все чекбоксы в форме в состоянии unchecked. Мы идём к первому инстансу компонента `checkboxesForm`, отмечаем второй и третий чекбоксы (переводим их в состояние checked), затем идём в другое место приложения где находится второй инстанс компонента `checkboxesForm`. Там мы уже должны увидеть второй и третий чекбоксы в состоянии checked и первый в состоянии unchecked (как и в той форме которую мы трогали первой).

Соответственно должно работать и в обратную сторону. Если мы теперь во втором инстансе в добавок к 2му и 3му чекбоксу отметим и первый - это же мзменение должно появиться в первом инстансе компонента с чекбоксами.

Пробовал делать через сервис с behaviourSubject, но даже код приводить не буду, там 100% написал какую-то ерунду.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как грамотно решить такую задачу. Спасибо! ♥

Comment: Хорошо, попробую накидать в песочнице.

Comment: чисто две формы и сервис добавьте, хватит

Comment: Упрощённый вид ситуации представлен в этой песочнице
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tbeddv?file=src/app/form.service.ts

В реальности компоненты лежат далеко друг от друга, совершенно в разных местах приложения.

Comment: Песочницу удалил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. сделать сервис в котором будет хранится переменная
2. создать в этом сервисе обозреваемую переменную, типа:

```js
private _cost = new Subject<any>();
public cost = this._cost.asObservable();
```

3. в целевом компоненте инжектить сервис, и подписаться на изменения обозреваемой переменной:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
    cost: any;
    subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private costsService: CostService) {
        this.subscription = this.costsService.cost.subscribe(input => {
          this.cost = input;
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Вот, как то так. Тут палюбому где-то опечатался, или забыл. Прислушивайтесь к tslint, и дебажным сообщениям, и будет работать.